# What is `intu-ec-client` listening on TCP port 8021?

Tags: macos, network, tcp

I'm wondering how I can either kill it or change the port it listens on.

Neither `lsof -nP -i4TCP:8021 | grep LISTEN` nor `netstat -av | grep 8021` or `launchctl list | awk 'NR>1 {print $3}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'launchctl list "%"' > launchctl.log` give me the process ID so I can kill it or get more info.

[image]

Comment: Google says port & name matches 'Intuit Entitlement Client' - so probably QuickBooks checking your license.

Comment: I'm having a hard time even locating the process id to manually kill it.

Comment: Why are you trying to kill it? If an app cannot contact its licensing server it will eventually lock you out. This is starting to sound like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: So, how did you find that particular process was listening on that particular port?

Comment: I'm working on a web server project that is supposed to listen on that port but when I try to start it up it fails with "address already in use" error. I could change it to start on whatever port I want but I'm wondering why that port is being used. I'm no QuickBooks user afaik. `lsof -nP -i4TCP:8021 | grep LISTEN`  gives nothing and `netstat -av | grep 8021` also comes back empty.

Answer (score 5):

So a colleague pointed me to a resource that kind of helps explaining the issue.

https://web.archive.org/web/20201014190758/https://lists.freeswitch.org/pipermail/freeswitch-users/2013-October/100619.html (kudos to [@vikasgarg86](https://twitter.com/vikasgarg86) for finding  and sending me that link).

Turns out there is this native `launchd` service `com.apple.ftp-proxy.plist` living at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.ftp-proxy.plist` that fires `/usr/libexec/ftp-proxy` (https://github.com/drduh/macOS-Security-and-Privacy-Guide/blob/master/launchd/15B42_launchd.csv#L94) which apparently binds to TCP port  8021.

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.apple.ftp-proxy</string>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>_ftp</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/libexec/ftp-proxy</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>ftp-proxy</string>
                <string>-p</string>
                <string>-n</string>
                <string>-V</string>
                <string>-D3</string>
                <string>-t1800</string>
        </array>
        <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Wait</key>
                <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>Sockets</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Listeners</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>SockNodeName</key>
                        <string>localhost</string>
                        <key>SockServiceName</key>
                        <string>8021</string>
                        <key>SockType</key>
                        <string>stream</string>
                </dict>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However that's only half the way into actually understanding what is going on. What the original author of the conversation linked here couldn't figure and myself too, is how that service got there in the first place. Why is it even running? and what are the consequences of changing the port from 8021 to something else.

Please comment bellow if you know the answers.

By the way `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.ftp-proxy.plist` does the job of stopping the service.